# unable to find retry_parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

We are using google app enigne (using version 1.9.18 while build & deploying app, language is Java)

We are using cron retry parameters in cron.yaml like following

```
retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_backoff_seconds: 5
    max_doublings: 5
```

While deploying we are getting following exception

```
unable to find retry_parameters on com.google.apphosting.utils.config.CronXml$Entity
```

Why we getting this exception, do we need to update our app engine version ??

Comment: I never worked with Java on GAE but shouldn't the [config files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cronref#syntax) there be `.xml` instead of `.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

`retry_parameters` is not a global setting; It pertains to each cron job separately.  Here is the syntax:

```
cron:
- description: "retry demo"
  url: /retry
  schedule: every 10 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

Comment: in the beginning of cron.yaml file I put the word cron: we have multiple cron jobs in the file. Do we need to put cron: for each cron job individually.

Comment: No.  The description of for each individual.  How about posting complete `cron.yaml`?