# Unable to find property 'retry_parameters'

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, yaml, google-cloud-sdk, retry-logic

As legacy standalone App Engine SDK (appcfg) will be deprecated as of July 30, 2019, it is necessary to migrate from cron.xml to cron.yaml.

When the first time I run mvn package appengine:deploy to deploy my application to google app engine, it fails with this error:-  `Unable to find property 'retry_parameters' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.CronXml$Entry`

[image]

My cron.yaml is as follows:

```
cron:
- description: Stripe apply post charge trial day Scheduar Task
  url: /schtask/stripepostchargetrialschtask
  schedule: every day 00:00
  timezone: Asia/Hong_Kong
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

I find that the same problem even occur when I am using the example cron.yaml below which appear in [cron.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#retry)

```
cron:
- description: "retry demo"
  url: /retry
  schedule: every 10 mins
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

Comment: Your YAML is invalid; `description` cannot have both a scalar value (`'Stripe […]'`) and a mapping value (`url: […]`). Concerning the error, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630894/unable-to-find-retry-parameters).

Comment: Please be sure that your cron.yaml file structure is like: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#retry

Comment: @flyx  I have edited cron.yaml as above but still fail with the same result. Do you have any idea? I am using Google Cloud SDK v255.0.0 beta v2019.05.17 bq v2.0.45 core v2019.07.19 gsutil v4.41

Comment: @WilliamAu-Yeung can you post new cron.yaml?

Comment: I have edited the question and the cron.yaml in that is already the new cron.yaml. thx for your help~

Comment: The library you are using is still configured to use .xml apparently. If you see the error message it says ".CronXml$Entry".

Comment: I just read the google document but still don't have any idea to configure to use .yaml. May you give me some hint?

Comment: Apparently the tool you are trying to use (mvn package appengine:deploy) has been [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven). You should use the [Gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle) tool in order to deploy your Java app. You should also read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration) documentation on how to migrate to the Cloud SDK.

Comment: thx Miguel, let me try~

Answer (score 0):

I've recently run into that issue myself and ended up moving the cron.yaml file from the war/WEB-INF folder it was in to my project's root folder. That alone fixed it for me. Wish I could give you a thorough explanation of the underlying mechanics but it would be filled with assumptions so I won't. Note that I deploy my application using Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.8.3 and do not include configuration files in deployments anymore. I update those individually using commands like `gcloud app deploy .\relative-path-to\cron.yaml`.